# How to ignore or pass through touch input on WKWebView if no html element is touched

Tags: ios, swift, input, wkwebview

I'm currently trying to have a WKWebView on top of some other views and have both be interactable. For the WebView I would like to have buttons etc. clickable, but touch input on the (transparent) background be passed on to the underlying views.

One thing I was able to get working is getting the pixel (using self.layer.render) and then checking if it is transparent and overriding the point method like this:

```
    public override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return !isTransparent(point: point)
    }
```

See also: [iOS WKWebView get RGBA pixel color from point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038306/ios-wkwebview-get-rgba-pixel-color-from-point?rq=2)

This does work, however it feels very expensive.

Another way would be to use JavaScript (using webView.evaluateJavaScript) to let it tell me if something was selected in the loaded page. However when I do this in point or hitTest overrides, the result is always stale, as it is async. However when I try to wait for the result (using a semaphore) it just freezes the App.

Is there a better and cleaner way to achieve this?